HttpRequest fails on some computers, but not on others, Error: response ended prematurely
We have a .NET 6 application which makes requests to a third party API.
About a month ago, requests from most of our computers started failing. The error we get is:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
the request. ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended
prematurely.

That's it, that's the whole error. No inner exception, unless I don't know how to log it properly.
We used Wireshark to check packet flow and it seems that the request does not leave the computer.
Only thing that has changed is the third party API started using Cloudflare.
Things that have been tested and didn't help:

Update Windows version to 22H2
Install all Windows updates
Check firewall
Compare registry with IIS Crypto
Reinstall our application
Compare .NET runtimes and make them equal
Try to launch our app as self-contained and see if that changes anything
Check if our external IP is blocked by the third party
Check TLS (requests failed with 1.1, 1.2, 1.3)
Check computer firewall
Windows proxy - it's off
Network adapter settings
ipconfig /flushdns
Reset windows proxy

What I also tried is to make a .NET console application and just send a request straight to the third party.
Code:
try
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;

    var apiUrl = "{apiUrl}";

    var httpClient = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddHttpClient()
            .BuildServiceProvider()
            .GetService<IHttpClientFactory>()
            .CreateClient();

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
    httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);

    var httpContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

    var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        //Version = HttpVersion.Version20,
        RequestUri = new Uri($"{apiUrl}PharmacyClaim/RegisterClaim"),
        Content = httpContent,
        Method = HttpMethod.Post
    };

    Log.Logger.Information("Making request to {0}, content:{1}{2}", httpClient.BaseAddress + "PharmacyClaim/RegisterClaim", Environment.NewLine, body);

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Log.Logger.Information("Response content: {0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, content);
    Log.Logger.Information("Response info: {0} HTTP version: {1}", Environment.NewLine, response.Version);
}
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
    Log.Logger.Error(e.InnerException, "Caught inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException?.Message);

    throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Logger.Error(ex, "Caught exception: {0}", ex.Message);

    throw;
}

Body is just an XML string.
I'm getting the same error, but what I could figure out is:

setting HTTP protocol version to 2.0 fixes the problem, but in some computers the request works with HTTP 1.1, so this really is just fixing the cause, not the reason

launching fiddler in PC makes the request work - I've read a bit about this and it seems like fiddler makes some kind of proxy for requests? No idea why using it makes the request work, but it seems like Fiddler alleviates a lot of .NET HTTP problems

using Postman to make requests works

using Curl to make requests works


The strangest thing is that in some computers the requests work, but in most of them they started failing.
Is this a Cloudflare issue, a .NET one, network issue? Can I get a more precise exception?
Any and all help would be appreciated.

Is ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true; necessary? I have read bad things about that. Actually I think HTTP/2 disables that setting, which may be why it works then.

removing ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
did not help

Update: very strange, but SQL server was updated to version 2022 in one computer and the requests started working. To me this does not make any sense, but our application does take some data from the database to send to the third party API. No idea how and why this works, but we're going to analyze this situation. Maybe the request envelope gets created differently.

Figured out the problem, which is another issue:
when launching the application as PC user, the application tries to access registry keys related to certificates and gets the error "ACCESS DENIED".
Data from process explorer:

